# Sending email using System.Net.Mail and outlook.com

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("name@hotmail.com", "name@hotmail.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name@hotmail.com", "password");

            mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
            mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
            client.Send(mail);
```

> Error message: Exception: Failure sending message. InnerException:
>   Unable to connect to remote server. A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 65.55.176.126:587

I am able to login into the account using the browser. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you able to ping `65.55.176.126:587` successfully?

Comment: Ping cannot find 65.55.176.126:587. Ping request timed out for 65.55.176.126.

Comment: I tried pinging `65.55.176.126` and it times out for me too, so it could be an issue with the mail server. It could be an antivirus or firewall.

Comment: Good tip: I am going to check both. Antivirus is Norton and I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: I disabled the firewall and antivirus and the request still timed out. Then the problem must be with the smtp server - right? "smtp-mail.outlook.com"

Answer (score 0):

Switched to smtp.gmail.com and it worked. I will let Microsoft solve this for the future!